# Search Solr by a dynamically generated field name

Tags: solr

I have a solr server that has a dynamicField of "phoneNumbers*"

When it receives a record from our mongo database via the mongo-connector it ends up look like this:

```
{
    phoneNumbers.0: "123-456-7890",
    phoneNumbers.1: "321-654-0987"
}
```

Is there a way for me to query against only the phone number fields. Something like this:

```
phoneNumbers.*:"123-456-7890"
```

I'm trying to prevent hard coding the search like so:

```
phoneNumbers.0:"123-456-7890" || phoneNumbers.1:"123-456-7890" || phoneNumbers.2:"123-456-7890"...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.0` and `.1` entries comes from the mongo connector flattening the documents to allow any subdocuments to be present in Solr.

The easiest way to solve this is to add a field to contain all the values and set the field as multivalued (so that it can keep multiple values), and then use a `copyField` instruction to tell Solr to put everything from the phoneNumbers.-fields into that single field. You can then search against that field to match any entry from a `phoneNumbers` field.

For example:

```
<copyField source="phoneNumbers.*" dest="phoneNumbers" />
```